# DNS resolution through a proxy

Tags: dns, proxy, wget, squid

I am behind a very capricious proxy (squid) and it seems only http requests made with a particular user-agent are allowed.

When fetching `google.com` from Google Chrome, I can see a `HTTP GET` on WireSharc. However, `wget` tries to resolve the DNS first through the default DNS servers which never answer.

How can I make `wget` or even `git` use the proxy instead of a direct DNS query?

Comment: If you're seeing that DNS requests are never answered, why do you think it's the fault of the proxy? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @roaima I never said it is the proxy's fault. I said wget is not doing the name resolution through the proxy.

Comment: Please could you clarify the relevance of "_it seems only http requests made with a particular user-agent are allowed_" to the DNS lookup issue you're describing. I don't see the connection. Thanks.

Comment: if wget is still doing a DNS lookup for the target site (not the proxy) then it's not set to use a proxy.  You could resolve the lookup problem with a hosts file entry, but that will just push the problem to the next stage, if it doesn't make a proper proxy request to the proxy, it will be rejected then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I make wget or even git use the proxy instead of a direct DNS query?

Set the proxy environment variable and it will do this straight up:

```
export http_proxy='http://proxy.contoso.com:3128/'
wget http://www.example.net/
```

Comment: I already did it. From chrome I get a `HTTP REQUEST` and from `wget` I still get a `TCP` request to the `DNS`. So Chrome is just asking the proxy and `wget` tries to resolve the DNS first.

Comment: @nowox I don't get any DNS lookup from `wget` in this configuration. What platform (OS) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

there is no mechanism to specify that the proxy should try a particular IP address for a particular host. You could change the URL from, say, http://example.com/mypage to http://33.33.33.33/mypage, but then the proxy server won't know the hostname to request. The modern web (HTTP/1.1) depends on a Host header always being present in a request, allowing one web server to serve multiple sites identified by their hostname.

Your best bet would be to configure the proxy server to use the DNS resolver of your choice. This would only be possible if you use a local proxy server that you control.

Resource - https://askubuntu.com/questions/447877/how-to-resolve-the-dns-locally-when-there-is-a-proxy-configured

Comment: So how is it possible that Chrome does not make a query to the DNS itself?